# Markdown: Convert multiple paragraphs into blockquote?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, markdown

I'm building a forum inside a Laravel 4 application. While viewing a thread, users can quote previous posts. A common feature.

Here's the basic setup I have now...

A user clicks on the quote icon above a post. The post's content is stored inside data-content, an attribute of the quote link.

```
<a class="quote" data-content="{{ $post->content }}" href="#">Quote</a>
```

Using jQuery, I populate a textarea for new posts with the data-content value:

```
$('.quote').click(function() {
    $('#new-post textarea').val($(this).data('content'));
});
```

And here lies the problem...

I would like to use Markdown's blockquote for displaying quoted data. I need to somehow add ">" to the beginning of each paragraph before populating the textarea.

Here's an example of a post and how it is stored in the DB (as you can see, there are no HTML tags etc, it is just raw paragraphs) - http://paste.laravel.com/12KO

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the expected output ? Also showing what you have tried would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure. In a nutshell, I just need to prefix each paragraph. http://paste.laravel.com/12KX

Comment: There are 2 ways. Using php, splitting by newline and then adding `>` to it. Or using regex `(?m)^`, replace by `>`.

Comment: Okay, great. Which way would you recommend?

Comment: The way you prefer as long as you understand the code.

Comment: Alright. Time to go and shape up on regex! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is adding tags `<blockquote> paragraph </blockquote>` html appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of anything more simple than `.replace("\n\n", ">\n\n")`

```
$('.quote').click(function() {
    var quote = $(this).data('content');
    var quotedText = quote.replace("\n\n", ">\n\n");
    $('#new-post textarea').val(quotedText);
});
```